# Computing the integration $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{nf(x)\ dx}{1+n^2 x^2}=\pi f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't have any idea that how to start this problem.

> Let $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then show that
>   $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{nf(x)\ dx}{1+n^2 x^2}=\pi f(0) $$

Comment: have you omitted a limit?

Comment: This definitely varies with respect to $n$. You meant to add $\lim_{n \to \infty}$

Comment: Yeah I made the change. Thanks, @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|\leq n^{-1}} \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\ dx+ \int_{n^{-1}\le|x| \le 1 } \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\ dx.
\end{align}

Comment: an excellent hint, +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

We first change variables using $y = nx$ to get
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2}f(x)\,dx 
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^n \frac{f(y/n)}{1+y^2}\,dy
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(0)}{1+y^2}\,dy \tag{Prove this!}
\\&=f(0)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy
\\&=\pi f(0)
\end{align}$$
The critical proof step has been left to OP, since OP merely asked for help starting the problem!